# Have company logos on a donut chart? - A noob's 2nd question

Tags: powerbi, icons

I can't figure out a way to integer company logos in my visuals. For instance I have a donut chart with monetary values corresponding to 4 client companies, and I want to insert their logos on their corresponding donut shares - or anywhere else where it'd make sense, like the legend or something.

I did read online that donut charts apparently simply do not support such features, so alternatives are what I am mostly looking for now.

[image: Like, that's the donut in question - monies as values and companies' names as details.]

Tried looking all this up, but all I could find was stand-alone visuals and the like, so either it wasn't what I look for, or it was simply straight up way too complex and away from my current skillset for me to even comprehend.

Edit : I may be dumb. It's at least easy to get them in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the donut chart - you could create a custom power bi tooltip that shoes the logo when hover - what I would probably do is just make a table or matrix with the images and figures.

Comment: That is indeed the conclusion I eventually reached, to the dismay of my manager. You've comforted me in my decision to stop trying for now xD